# Regex to remove empty tags HTML except images

Tags: regex

I have a regex to remove empty tags HTML, like `<p></p>` or `<span></span>`, but inside them I can have images and I want to ignore the tag `<img>`. My regex:

```
(<(?!\/)[^>]+>)+(<\/[^>]+>)+
```

My uses cases:

[image]

I want to ignore the last line, because I have an image inside the tag.

Check the live editor: https://regex101.com/r/81M8VR/1

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following seems to work:

```
(<(?!\/)((?!img)[^>])+>)+(<\/[^>]+>)+
```

https://regex101.com/r/A0N1rL/1